# MongoDB NodeJS Query and paginate multiple collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I am dealing with a case where I need to render of listing of several entities on one page, with one pagination.

I.g.: Given 3 collections, ***People***, **Robots** and **ETs**. Now I'd need to list them all in a `/everybody` route that renders a listing page with a pagination and some filters.

As far as I can tell the only way to do that in MongoDB is to query each collection manually and handle the pagination in the application. Are there any other/better ways ?

Comment: I think so, although you can "join" collections in aggregation using $lookup.

Comment: $lookups will only work when you have less amount to data. It will not work if you have more than 50,000 records in each collections